# Elasticsearch query to match two different fields with exact values

Tags: elasticsearch, boolean

I want to find the record in my elasticsearch index where it should match field "connectorSpecific.hostname.keyword" with value "tyco-fire.com"  and field "hasForms" with value true.

Below is my elasticsearch query:

```
GET index1/_search
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "connectorSpecific.hostname.keyword":  "tyco-fire.com" }},
        { "match": { "hasForms": true   }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query is returning records which also has field "hasForms" with value false. Not sure why.I am using a boolean should query.Any help is appreciated

Comment: since you're trying to match a boolean you should try using [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-term-query.html) query instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want both constraints to match, then you should use `bool/filter` (or `bool/must` would work as well but since you're doing exact matching, you don't need scoring at all), like this:

```
GET index1/_search
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "match": { "connectorSpecific.hostname.keyword":  "tyco-fire.com" }},
        { "match": { "hasForms": true   }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```